# How to convert string from input type="datetime-local" to datetime in symfony without FormBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, symfony-3.2

I have date with time string: `array(2) { ["available_from"]=> string(16) "2020-07-30T12:26" ["available_to"]=> string(16) "2020-07-30T23:32" }`

Input:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Ważna od:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="availableDateFrom" name="date[available_from]" class="datetimepicker required"
           data-min-date="{{ 'now'|date('Y-m-d') }}"
           value="{% if available_offer_hours.availableFrom is defined %}{{ available_offer_hours.availableFrom }}{% else %}{{ 'now'|date("Y-m-d") }} 00:00{% endif %}"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Ważna do:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="availableDateTo" name="date[available_to]" class="datetimepicker required"
           data-min-date="{{ 'now'|date('Y-m-d') }}"
           value="{% if available_offer_hours.availableTo is defined %}{{ available_offer_hours.availableTo }}{% else %}{{ 'now'|date("Y-m-d") }} 15:45{% endif %}"/>
</div>
```

I use form method POST and get the value in controller by: $request->request->get('date').
This one of example from unsuccessful attempts:

```
$availableDate = [
     'available_from' => date_create($request->request->get('date[available_from]')),
     'available_to' => $this->changeDateTimezone($request->request->get('date[available_to]'))
   ];
var_dump($availableDate);
```

Everytime when i try to use: \DateTime::createFromFormat, new \DateTime(string ), strtotime(), etc. i got bool(false), actual datetime or datetime from year above 1970 - but not converted string to object dateTime from input name="date[available_form]".

I need help how to do it properly - (get DateTime object from string value: "date[available_from]") / what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that `$request->request->get('date[available_from]')` is returning `null`. Try using dot notation `$request->request->get('date.available_from')` or `$request->request->get('date')['available_from']`

Comment: It was like You said: $request->request->get('date[available_from]') is returning null.
It's already fixed. It's correct to use: \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $availableFrom) in this case.
Where $availableFrom is created variable with value of input name availableFrom instead 'date[available_from]'
 I had some problem with data cache so i got old data return on each notation change.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess but you are probably missing the 'T' when parsing the datestrings, T is just a separator in this place, unluckily you did not provide any trys but this could work:

```
$str = "2020-07-30T23:32" ;
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i", $str);
echo $dt->format("d.m.Y H:i");
```

outputs for me:

```
30.07.2020 23:32
```

Comment: I have provide This try and also try like : "Y-m-d\TH:i'
boolean is returned

Comment: hm I tested it and its working for me, check the updated code, you can copy paste into php sandbox